# When browser closed update table and destroy session using ajax

Tags: javascript, events, browser, window

I need to update a table when user closed the browser window and also want to destroy session.

Comment: I will try to close this dreadful question!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty - have a client-side script that constantly reports (using a timer)  that users page is still open.

Comment: By constantly what do you mean. Every second?

Comment: basically if we using onload or onbeforeload event into the page . its not good bcoz its fire of each refresh or postback and we are also not use to check the browser client X <0 or Y  <0  its also not work so guys think about it ..... remember we need to update a table of dabase to ......

Comment: i don't understand you comment. be descriptive.

Comment: Read my answer again - the page will report using js timer function to the server that it is still open (sending normal http query).